# String as Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, text, pathgeometry, formatted-text

I'm trying to place a simple `string` inside a `Rectangle`. I'm using `GeometryGroup` for that purpose, and here is my code:

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {
        var geoGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        var text = new FormattedText("Hello", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Times New-Roman"), 150, ShapeContainer.Color);

        var geometry = text.BuildGeometry(ShapeContainer.Location); 

        geoGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 100)));
        geoGroup.Children.Add(geometry);

        return geoGroup;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the text I'm getting is doubled (see attached image).

[image]

Can't I convert `Label`-style text into `Geometry` for printing it alongside a `Rectangle`?

Comment: Looks like the text has red stroke and no fill. Try changing it to no stroke and red fill.

Comment: You may also want to replace `GeometryGroup` by `CombinedGeometry` in order to exclude the text geometry from the Rectangle fill.